# Having A Timer Complete A Different Task Every 2 Seconds C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to have the timer say a different line every 2 seconds instead of adding all of the text into the text box at once, I wanna give the user the opportunity to read the dialog instead of it all being added into the box at once. This is the code I have so far but it doesn't seem to output the text.

```
private void OaksSpeakingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Starting Oaks basic speaking timer
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Start();
        ProfessorTxt.Text += "LLLLLLL";
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Stop();
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Start();
        ProfessorTxt.Text += "\rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.";
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Stop();
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Start();
        ProfessorTxt.Text += "\nttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt!";
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Timers work a little differently than you're expecting them to. You're using it like a "sleep", but really, they invoke a delegate when the time elapses. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component) for an example.

Comment: i see the code above will just show the last line.. what about having an `if` to check the current text and changes to the next pattern?

Comment: You mean an if statement to check if the first line was typed? if (line typed = true) than type next line.

Comment: Yeah the first problem here is you have to understand how a timer works, when you do, then you will have to work out how to make a queue or a list of things to say, and itterate/pop that queue/list every time it hits the timmer event

Answer (score 2):

You could put all the intended text in a [`Queue<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and dequeue the next string whenever the timer fires:

```
private Queue<string> messages = new Queue<string> 
{
    "LLLLLLL",
    "\rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.",
    "\nttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt!"
};

private void OaksSpeakingTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (messages.Count == 0) 
    {
        OaksSpeakingTimer.Stop();
        return;
    }

    var message = messages.Dequeue();
    ProfessorTxt.Text += message;
}
```